# Are table value parameter from PHP to SQL Server supported in Microsoft's PHP - SQL Server (v2.0) driver?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, driver

Does the official Microsoft Sql Server driver v2.0 for PHP support table value paramerers?  I'd like to call a stored procedure from php and pass in a table.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060599/php-sql-server-table-value-parameter

Comment: Can you note the driver differences in your question? I nearly closed this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Tim Post, a new version of the driver (v2.0) has been released since that answer was posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Php SQL Server table value parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060599/php-sql-server-table-value-parameter/2060793#2060793)

Comment: a new version of the driver (v2.0) has been releases since that answer was posted.

Comment: I can't find anything that says the v2.0 supports tvp