# Pass array to SQL Server Function/Stored Procedure using PHP PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sql-server-2008-r2, table-valued-parameters

I've gotten to a point where I absolutely need some clean way to safely pass lists/arrays from php to SQL server stored procedures and table value functions. The PHP SQL server driver still does not support table valued parameters, according to [Microsoft docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296193(v=sql.105).aspx).

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060599/php-sql-server-table-value-parameter), using XML was suggested as an alternative.

Does anyone have a code sample for passing the equivalent of a TVP using an XML stream and PHP PDO or another clean alternative?

Comment: guessing... Would it be useful to be able to convert from JSON to XML that i believe  SQL handles quite well? This may be useful: [A lossless xml to json and json to xml converter (and csv/xlsx/yaml)](https://github.com/DracoBlue/Craur).

Answer (score 1):

The primitive, but foolproof solution, is to pass it as a delimited string, and use a SPLIT function in your proc to convert the string to a table that you can then JOIN to.

Google SQL SPLIT FUNCTION to get free cut-n-paste code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use xml, but a better, more compact idea would be to use JSON.

```
$myArray = array("thing 1", "thing 2", "thing 3");
$sql = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` (`array_data`) VALUES (:myArray)");
$sql->execute(array(":myArray"=>json_encode($myArray)));
```

Then when you pull the data back out of the database you can convert it back into an array with:

```
$myArray = json_decode($res['myArray'], true);
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm not trying to store the array in the database, rather I want to read it into a stored procedure or user defined function as a parameter and be able to join it to other tables within sql server so I can use it as part of an inline select query if that makes any sense.