# Is it possible to send XML format with PHP to sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

Good day, I'm trying to import an XML file from my website (PHP). I have do some research about it and i found this [Passing datatable to a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320594/passing-datatable-to-a-stored-procedure) but that for `C#`. So, is it possible to send it?

here is my stored Procedure

```
USE [sales_web]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertSALESPOS]    Script Date: 11/30/2016 09:19:48 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertSALESPOS]   

@HeaderTemp HeaderTemp readonly,                  
@DetailTemp DetailTemp readonly,                  
@PaymentTemp PaymentTemp readonly,                  
@VoucherTemp VoucherTemp readonly,                  
@LedgerTemp LedgerTemp readonly                  

AS                  
BEGIN           

set nocount on;

begin try                  
begin transaction                  

 select ID, TransactionNo, TransactionDate, TotalTransaction, LocationID, UserID, CustomerCode, SendStatus      
 into #HeaderTemp from @HeaderTemp             
 where TransactionNo not in(SELECT TransactionNo from TransactionHeader with(nolock))                  

    INSERT INTO dbo.SalesOrderHeader (TransactionNo, DocumentNo, TransDate, ETADate, ExternalDocument, Reference, RefTransNo, Category, CustomerCode, Remark, Remark2, TermOfPayment,                  
    Currency, Rate, UseVAT, SubTotal, DiscPercent, DiscAmount, GrandTotal, TotalReceivable, FromCustomerCode, PostingStatus, PostingBy, PostingDate, CreatedDate, CreatedBy, ModifiedDate,                  
    ModifiedBy, CustomerReceivable, LocationCode, VatPercent, VatAmount, FinalReleasedDate_Outlet)                  
 select h.TransactionNo, h.TransactionNo as DocumentNo, cast(left(h.TransactionDate,len(h.TransactionDate)-6) as datetime) as TransDate,                  
    cast(left(h.TransactionDate,len(h.TransactionDate)-6) as datetime) as ETADate, '' as ExternalDocument, '' as Reference, '' as RefTransNo,                  
    'POS' as Category, h.CustomerCode, '' as Remark, '' as Remark2, Cast('' as Datetime) as TermOfPayment, 'IDR' as Currency, Cast(1 as Float) as Rate,                  
    Cast(0 as Bit) as UseVAT, Cast(SUM(d.TotalAmountAfterDisc) as Float) as SubTotal, Cast(0 as Float) as DiscPercent, Cast(0 as Float) as DiscAmount,                  
    Cast(SUM(d.TotalAmountAfterDisc) as Float) as GrandTotal, Cast(SUM(d.TotalAmountAfterDisc) as Float) as TotalReceivable,                
    h.CustomerCode as FromCustomerCode, Cast(0 as Bit) as PostingStatus, '' as PostingBy, Cast('' as Datetime) as PostingDate,                   
    cast(left(h.TransactionDate,len(h.TransactionDate)-6) as datetime) as CreatedDate, h.UserID as CreatedBy,                  
    cast(left(h.TransactionDate,len(h.TransactionDate)-6) as datetime) as ModifiedDate, h.UserID as ModifiedBy, h.CustomerCode as CustomerReceivable,                  
    h.CustomerCode as LocationCode, Cast(0 as Float) as VatPercent, Cast(0 as Float) as VatAmount, cast(left(h.TransactionDate,len(h.TransactionDate)-6) as datetime) as FinalReleasedDate_Outlet                  
    from @HeaderTemp h                   
    Inner Join @DetailTemp d on h.id = d.TransactionID and h.CustomerCode = d.CustomerCode                  
 Where h.TransactionNo IN (select TransactionNo from #HeaderTemp with(nolock))                  
    Group By h.TransactionNo, TransactionDate , h.CustomerCode, h.UserID                  

    Insert Into dbo.SalesOrderDetail                  
 SELECT h.TransactionNo + '-' + Cast(ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order By h.TransactionNo) as Varchar) as TransactionNo, h.TransactionNo as SalesOrderTransNo,                  
    h.TransactionNo as RefTransNo, (ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order By h.TransactionNo))*1000 as [LineNo], isnull(d.ItemCode,''), d.Quantity, isnull(d.MainUOMCode,'') as UOM,                  
    d.UnitPrice, 0 as DiscountPercent, 0 as VatPercent, (d.Quantity*d.UnitPrice) as AmountPrice,                   
    ((d.Quantity*d.UnitPrice)-d.TotalAmountAfterDisc) as AmountDiscount, 0 as AmountVat,                   
    d.TotalAmountAfterDisc as Total, d.TotalAmountAfterDisc as Receivable,                  
 d.UnitPrice as UnitPriceAfterReceivable, '' as ExtraRemark, '' as ExtraRemark2,                    
    cast(left(h.TransactionDate,len(h.TransactionDate)-6) as datetime) as CreatedDate, h.UserID as CreatedBy,                    
    cast(left(h.TransactionDate,len(h.TransactionDate)-6) as datetime) as ModifiedDate, h.UserID as ModifiedBy                   
    from @HeaderTemp h                    
    Inner Join @DetailTemp  d on h.id = d.TransactionID and h.CustomerCode = d.CustomerCode                  
 Where h.TransactionNo IN (select TransactionNo from #HeaderTemp with(nolock))                      

    Insert Into dbo.SalesOrderPayment                  
 Select h.TransactionNo + '-' + Cast(ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order By h.TransactionNo) as Varchar) as TransactionNo, h.TransactionNo as SalesOrderTransNo,                  
    p.PaymentMethodCode, p.TotalDue, p.TotalTendered                   
    From @HeaderTemp h                   
    Left Join @PaymentTemp p on h.id = p.TransactionID                   
    and h.CustomerCode = p.CustomerCode                  
    Where h.TransactionNo IN (select TransactionNo from #HeaderTemp with(nolock))                  
 --cast(left(h.TransactionDate,len(h.TransactionDate)-6) as datetime)                  

    Insert Into dbo.SalesOrderVoucher                  
 Select h.TransactionNo + '-' + Cast(ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order By h.TransactionNo) as Varchar) as TransactionNo, h.TransactionNo as SalesOrderTransNo,                   
    v.VoucherVendor as Voucher, Case When v.VoucherType = '1' Then 'NOMINAL' Else 'PERCENT' End as VoucherType, v.VoucherValue, v.VoucherAmount                   
    From @HeaderTemp h                   
    Left Join @VoucherTemp v On h.CustomerCode = v.CustomerCode And h.ID = v.TransactionID                   
 Where h.TransactionNo IN (select TransactionNo from #HeaderTemp with(nolock))      

    Insert Into dbo.ItemLedgerEntry(TransactionNo, SequenceNo, DocumentNo, EntryType,                    
 CustomerCode, ItemCode, PostingDate, Quantity, UomCode, CreatedDate, CreatedBy)                   
 Select TransactionNo, SequenceNo, DocumentNo, EntryType,                   
 CustomerCode, ItemCode, cast(left(PostingDate,len(PostingDate)-6) as datetime) as PostingDate, Cast(Quantity as Float) as Quantity, UomCode, cast(left(CreatedDate,len(CreatedDate)-6) as datetime) as CreatedDate, CreatedBy                    
  From @LedgerTemp                   
 Where DocumentNo in (select Transactionno from #HeaderTemp with(nolock))                  



 drop table #HeaderTemp                   
 Select 'Succes' as [Status]  
commit transaction                  
end try                   
begin catch                  
 rollback                          
  insert into XMLLOGERROR values(getdate(), 'SALESPOS', ERROR_MESSAGE())  
end catch                  
end
```

I have try this way

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file($file);
                    $HeaderTemp     = array();
                    $DetailTemp     = array();
                    $PaymentTemp    = array();
                    $LedgerTemp     = array();
                    $VoucherTemp    = array(); 
                    $tambahan = array('session_id' => date('d:h:i:s'));
                    $login = str_replace(' ', '', $this->input->cookie('cookie_webstore_user'));
                    $session = $login.$tambahan['session_id'];

                    foreach ($xml->HeaderTemp as $HeaderTempnya)
                                {   
                                    $HeaderTemp[] = $HeaderTempnya;
                                }
                            foreach ($xml->DetailTemp as $DetailTempnya)
                                {
                                    $DetailTemp[] = $DetailTempnya;
                                }   
                            foreach($xml->PaymentTemp as $PaymentTempnya)
                                {
                                    $PaymentTemp[] = $PaymentTempnya;
                                }
                            foreach($xml->LedgerTemp as $LedgerTempnya)
                                {
                                    $LedgerTemp[] = $LedgerTempnya;
                                }
                            foreach($xml->VoucherTemp as $VoucherTempnya)
                                {
                                    $VoucherTemp[] = $VoucherTempnya;
                                }           

                    if($VoucherTempnya != ""){
                    $this->modelmodel->showsingle("[InsertSALESPOS] '{$HeaderTemp}','{$DetailTemp}','{$PaymentTemp}','{$VoucherTemp}','{$LedgerTemp}'");
                    }else{
                    $this->modelmodel->showsingle("[InsertSALESPOS] '{$HeaderTemp}','{$DetailTemp}','{$PaymentTemp}','','{$LedgerTemp}'");
                    }
```

With my script above i get this error

> Error Number: 22018/206
>
> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client
>   10.0][SQL Server]Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with HeaderTemp
>
> [InsertSALESPOS]
>   'Array','Array','Array','','Array'
>
> Filename:
>   D:/xampp/htdocs/new_store/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line
>   Number: 691

Sorry for my bad english.

Ok. I have solved my problem above with different way. I'm just curious about it if impossible, please explain why.

Comment: I don't believe PHP supports TVPs. I believe you'd either have to pass XML or a string and have SQL parse it and break it into tables for your queries.

Comment: I hope this link will be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060599/php-sql-server-table-value-parameter/2060793#2060793

Comment: @SergeyLebedev so, until now still not supported?

Comment: Yes, you can pass in XML to SQL Server, but not as a table. You would have to pass it in as an XML item, then shred the XML using TSQL XML handling code inside the stored procedure and place the results into the table as needed.  How exactly that would work most efficiently really depends on data structure and the version of SQL Server you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with `openrowset` command to load the xml into a table in sql server, for more information go through the link `https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/`

Comment: So, with `php`, how do you send it ?

Comment: Write those sql statements in to stored procedure with file name as parameter and then call it from php.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use an array as a value for a field, where the field type is defined as a varchar.

You should loop true the array you are now trying to use for insert and execute the insert statement in each loop using the current value in the loop

Comment: yeah. I know. I have done that. Can i send it in XML format.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use PHP as it can be directly inserted through MySQL. The command would be like

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/pathtofile/file.xml' 
INTO TABLE my_tablename(col1, col2, ...);
```

For More information about Loading XML data read Mysql Docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html)

Comment: SQL Server != MySQL