# Pass array to SQL server stored procedure from PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to call stored procedure on SQL server and pass array of items. Example passing student info with multiple awards:

```
[awards]
id, description
1, Award 1
2, Award 2
3, Award 3
4, Award 4
5, Award 5

students:
id, first_name, last_name
```

I need to pass one student with multiple award ID's (this number can vary). The end result wold be as follow:

```
[students]
17, John, Doe [INSERTED]  

[student_awards]
id, student_id, award_id
1, 17, 2 [INSERTED]
1, 17, 3 [INSERTED]
1, 17, 5 [INSERTED]
```

I am not asking for stored procedure - I can write it myself. I am asking help in understanding of a way to pass array with multiple `award_id`'s.

Thank you!

Comment: what you have tried??

Comment: You might want to look at [this so post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060599/php-sql-server-table-value-parameter)

Comment: Nothing so far. But I think that my question is clear ... Cannot find an answer: is it possible to pass an array as a single argument to stored procedure from php to SQL server? Above is just an example...

Comment: Actually, according to the link in the answer I've linked in, a UDT data type is mapped to PHP's Stream2 data type. I know nothing about PHP so I don't know if it helps you.